# I am unable to change background color to the 2D array JButton (size is the Variable describing size of 2D array)

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

```
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
        final int i=x;
        for(int y=0;y<size;y++)
        {
            final int j=y;
            bt[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JToggleButton btn = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
                    btn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here I tried with  `JButton btn= (Jbutton) e.getSource()` also but doesn't work.

This code failed as well:

```
for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
{
    final int i=x;
    for(int y=0;y<size;y++)
    {

        final int j=y;
        bt[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
                    {
                        if(e.getSource()==bt[i][j])
                        {
                            bt[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The BackGround  Color should be changed after i click on the button.

Comment: See if you can get what you want with one button: run a test with a simple gui with one button and see if you can get it to work. If you can get it to work with one, you can get it to work with many. If you fail post it here see:
[mcve]